# How to display man2many fields in list view in odoo 8?

Tags: listview, treeview, many-to-many, odoo-8, odoo

I tried two ways to display many2many field in list view but none of them worked:

1) `<field name="test_ids"/>` --> It shows just the number of records.(i.e. (3 records))

2) `<field name="test_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>` --> It shows the ids of records. (i.e. 2,3,4)

How to achive this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally,

```
<field name="test_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
```

must work.

The reason the m2m columns displaying the ids is either your co-model does not contain either **name** field or **_rec_name** declaration in the model.

Comment: It contains "name" field. "many2many_tags" is working in the one2many field of the form view but not in the list view.

Comment: @Ankit, Be clear to your question. many2many_tags will surely work in the tree view for the many2many field, not for the one2many field.

Comment: Tnx. There was some issue in my db. I created new db and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
<field name="test_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>
```

Comment: I already tried this but not working. It shows the ids of records. (i.e. 2,3,4)

Comment: may be you tried widget="many2many". did you tried widget="many2many_tags"?

Comment: Tnx. There was some issue in my db. I created new db and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you don't have record name on related model. You have two options:

- add field name in related model.
- define _rec_name on related model to point into correct field with name you want to be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

To display many2many field in list view you must use `many2many_tags`

Now it shows you the list of ids because Odoo don't know how to represent
 the record in the relation field.

How to tell Odoo how he represent the record there is two ways:

1- easy one is using the `rec_name` if you record can be represented by a value of a field
   for example country, the name of the country is enough to distinct records

```py
   class YourClass..
      _name = 'your_model_name'
      _rec_name = 'field_name' # here put the name of the field
```

2- second one is when a one field cannot represent the record use `name_get`

```py
class YourClass..
    _name = 'your_model_name'
    .....
    .....

    # implement this method in you model class
    @api.multi
    def name_get(self):
        """ change representation of the record by concatinating two field"""
        result = []
        for record in self:
            result.append((record.id, _("%s %s") % (
                  record.some_field, record.some_other_field)))
        return result
```